# How to incorporate an array into an object to be sent via web services

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am creating a new case in a third party vendor that uses a web service.
The object has an array associated with it.  When I try to add the array back to the object, I get the following message:

> System.InvalidCase Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'BL.CLaim' to type 'BL.CaseService.Claim'

Here is my code:

```
Dim _case As CaseService.[Case] = New CaseService.[Case]()

_case.programId = 777          
_case.programOfficeId = 123456       
_case.name = "Blah"

Dim claims As _case.Claim = New _case.Claim
Dim claim As Object = New Claim

claim.claimNumber = "111111"
claim.insuredFirstName = "Billy"
claim.insuredLastName = "Bob"
```

The error is happening at

```
_case.claims(0) = claim
```

Comment: You need to start by setting `Option Strict On`.  `System.Object` is not a one size fits all type.  It does not have a `claimNumber ` property for instance.  We have no idea what `CaseService` looks like, but there is plenty there that looks...odd.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error you have two different Claim objects, one under BL and another under BL.CaseService.  Even if they are both called Claim and have all the same properties, etc. they are not the same object and can’t be interchanged.  Try declaring Claim like this:

Dim Claim As New BL.CaseService.Claim